# Tried to extract urls by using soup.select and soup.find_all

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

This is a part of the HTML source code of a web page:

```
<a href="http://www.abcde.com"> <img style="width:100%" src="/FileUploads/B/763846f.jpg" alt="search" title="search" /></a>
<a id="parts_img01" href="/Result?s=9&amp;type=%E4&amp;name=%E9"><h4 style=""><i class="fa f-c" aria-hidden="true"></i>apple</h4></a>
<a id="parts_img02" href="/Result?s=12&amp;type=%E4&amp;name=%E4"><h4 style=""><i class="fa f-c" aria-hidden="true"></i>banana</h4></a>
<a id="parts_img03" href="/Result?s=10&amp;type=%E4&amp;name=%E8"><h4 style=""><i class="fa f-c" aria-hidden="true"></i>cherry</h4></a>
<a id="parts_img07" href="/Result?s=14&amp;type=%E4&amp;name=%E8"><h4 style=""><i class="fa f-c" aria-hidden="true"></i>melon</h4></a>
```

And I want to extract the urls I want, like the one start with /Result?
I just learned that you can use soup.find_all and soup.select in beautiful soup.

soup.find_all:

```
icon = soup.find_all(id = re.compile("parts_img"))
```

and one of the result will successfully print:

```
<a href="/Result?s=9&amp;type=%E4&amp;name=%E9" id="parts_img01"><h4 style=""><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa f-c"></i>apple</h4></a>
```

soup.select:

```
for item in soup.select(".fa f-c"):
    print(item['href'])
```

And this is not working...

Is there possibly a way I can extract urls directly from html?
I just want to print:

```
/Result?s=9&amp;type=%E4&amp;name=%E9
/Result?s=12&amp;type=%E4&amp;name=%E4
/Result?s=10&amp;type=%E4&amp;name=%E8
/Result?s=14&amp;type=%E4&amp;name=%E8
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this code will illustrate extracting `href` from the given html.

```
 html = """<a href="http://www.abcde.com"> <img style="width:100%" src="/FileUploads/B/763846f.jpg" alt="search" title="search" /></a>
<a id="parts_img01" href="/Result?s=9&amp;type=%E4&amp;name=%E9"><h4 style=""><i class="fa f-c" aria-hidden="true"></i>apple</h4></a>
<a id="parts_img02" href="/Result?s=12&amp;type=%E4&amp;name=%E4"><h4 style=""><i class="fa f-c" aria-hidden="true"></i>banana</h4></a>
<a id="parts_img03" href="/Result?s=10&amp;type=%E4&amp;name=%E8"><h4 style=""><i class="fa f-c" aria-hidden="true"></i>cherry</h4></a>
<a id="parts_img07" href="/Result?s=14&amp;type=%E4&amp;name=%E8"><h4 style=""><i class="fa f-c" aria-hidden="true"></i>melon</h4></a>"""
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup
import re
from urllib.parse import urljoin
parser = Soup(html, "lxml")
href = [ urljoin("http://www.abcde.com", a["href"]) for a in parser.findAll("a", {"id" : re.compile('parts_img.*')})]
print(href)
```

Comment: It's working! Thank you! I have another question, the urls are not complete in this case. I need to join www.abcde.com with all the url, but since href is a list, it will have an error like this: Cannot mix str and non-str arguments. I use urljoin by the way.

Comment: Please find the use of urllib.parse library to join relative url to absolute in original answer

Answer (score 2):

To get the same output without using regex:

```
html = """
 <a href="http://www.abcde.com"> <img style="width:100%" src="/FileUploads/B/763846f.jpg" alt="search" title="search" /></a>
<a id="parts_img01" href="/Result?s=9&amp;type=%E4&amp;name=%E9"><h4 style=""><i class="fa f-c" aria-hidden="true"></i>apple</h4></a>
<a id="parts_img02" href="/Result?s=12&amp;type=%E4&amp;name=%E4"><h4 style=""><i class="fa f-c" aria-hidden="true"></i>banana</h4></a>
<a id="parts_img03" href="/Result?s=10&amp;type=%E4&amp;name=%E8"><h4 style=""><i class="fa f-c" aria-hidden="true"></i>cherry</h4></a>
<a id="parts_img07" href="/Result?s=14&amp;type=%E4&amp;name=%E8"><h4 style=""><i class="fa f-c" aria-hidden="true"></i>melon</h4></a>
"""
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
for link in soup.select("[id^='parts_img']"):
    print(link['href'])
```

Result:

```
/Result?s=9&type=%E4&name=%E9
/Result?s=12&type=%E4&name=%E4
/Result?s=10&type=%E4&name=%E8
/Result?s=14&type=%E4&name=%E8
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

top_url = 'https://a-certain.org/item-index'
response = requests.get(top_url)
html = response.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
items = soup.select('a[href^="http://a-certain.org/items"]')
for item in items:
        print(items['href'])
```

Output is

```
http://a-certain.org/items/item1/
http://a-certain.org/items/item2/
http://a-certain.org/items/item3/
```